# Swipe or click a div from botton in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, plugins, ionic2

[image: in the screen shot when the user clicks the botton arrow , a new content should slide from the bottom to top][image: after the user functionality it should look like from the second picture as it is, means the new content should sit on the old content ,]

in the screen shot-1 when the user clicks the botton arrow or swipe from bottom to top, a new content should slide from the bottom to top

in the creen-shot-2 ,after the user functionality , it should look like from the second picture as it is, means the new content should sit on the old content

how do we achieve this in ionice 2 . Is there a plugin or any term for this ? . can somebody break the login behind this in a mobile view . Exact example when you slide from the botton in iphone you get that functionality what I mean . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called `ion-pull-up-footer`. You can check this [here](https://github.com/arielfaur/ionic-pullup).

Comment: Than you very much i got the solution from 
[link](https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-a-sliding-drawer-component-for-ionic-2/)

Comment: This is brilliant and easy . Meeting my requirements ,thank you very much once again

Comment: Is there we can set the height according to the content ? .